# Como pegar campo específico de um array de objetos utilizando o componente autocomplete do material ui

Tags: react, material-ui

Tenho um componente autocomplete do Material UI, criado utilizando o pacote `formik-material-ui`. O componente renderiza um array de objetos do modelo abaixo:

```
const teams = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Barcelona'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Real Madrid'},
];
```

Quando alterar a seleção (`onInputChange`) do `Autocomplete`, preciso pegar somente o ID da seleção, o que acontece é que estou pegando o nome.

Segue o código completo: [image: Edit autocomplete material-ui example (forked)].

Qual seria o procedimento correto para pegar o ID?

---

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Formik, Form, Field} from 'formik';
import {Button, LinearProgress} from '@material-ui/core';
import MuiTextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import {
  Autocomplete,
  AutocompleteRenderInputParams,
} from 'formik-material-ui-lab';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

const teams = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Barcelona'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Real Madrid'},
];

const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState('');

  const handleShowId = React.useCallback((event, value) => {
    alert(value.id);
    setSelected(event.target);
  }, []);

  console.log(selected);

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        autocomplete: [],
      }}
      onSubmit={(values, {setSubmitting}) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSubmitting(false);
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }, 500);
      }}
    >
      {({submitForm, isSubmitting, touched, errors}) => (
        <Form>
          {isSubmitting && <LinearProgress />}
          <Box margin={1}>
            <Field
              name="autocomplete"
              component={Autocomplete}
              options={teams}
              value={selected}
              getOptionLabel={(option: any) => option.name}
              style={{width: 300}}
              onChange={handleShowId}
              renderInput={(params: AutocompleteRenderInputParams) => (
                <MuiTextField
                  {...params}
                  error={touched['autocomplete'] && !!errors['autocomplete']}
                  helperText={touched['autocomplete'] && errors['autocomplete']}
                  label="Autocomplete"
                  variant="outlined"
                />
              )}
            />
          </Box>
          <Box margin={1}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              disabled={isSubmitting}
              onClick={submitForm}
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: https://material-ui.com/pt/components/autocomplete/#controllable-states

Comment: `onChange` em vez de `onInputChange` devolve o objeto selecionado

Comment: Certo, eu havia pensado nessa abordagem, o problema é que o campo está limpando após o onChange. Atualizei o SANDBOX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o seguinte código consegue resolver seu problema

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Formik, Form, Field} from 'formik';
import {Button, LinearProgress} from '@material-ui/core';
import MuiTextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import {
  Autocomplete,
  AutocompleteRenderInputParams,
} from 'formik-material-ui-lab';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

const teams = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Barcelona'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Real Madrid'},
];

const App = () => {
  const handleShowId = React.useCallback((event, value) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(value.id));
  }, []);

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        autocomplete: [],
      }}
      onSubmit={(values, {setSubmitting}) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSubmitting(false);
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }, 500);
      }}
    >
      {({submitForm, isSubmitting, touched, errors}) => (
        <Form>
          {isSubmitting && <LinearProgress />}
          <Box margin={1}>
            <Field
              name="autocomplete"
              component={Autocomplete}
              options={teams}
              getOptionLabel={(option: any) => option.name}
              style={{width: 300}}
              onChange={handleShowId}
              renderInput={(params: AutocompleteRenderInputParams) => (
                <MuiTextField
                  {...params}
                  error={touched['autocomplete'] && !!errors['autocomplete']}
                  helperText={touched['autocomplete'] && errors['autocomplete']}
                  label="Autocomplete"
                  variant="outlined"
                />
              )}
            />
          </Box>
          <Box margin={1}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              disabled={isSubmitting}
              onClick={submitForm}
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Como o comentario acima diz o a propriedade `onInputChange` representa o valor que esta dentro da caixa de texto, enquanto o `onChange` representa o objeto em si. Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Certo, eu havia pensado nessa abordagem, o problema é que o campo está limpando após o onChange. Atualizei o SANDBOX.

Comment: @Fred Agora não consigo testar pois estou ocupado mas acredito que se você passar ```event.preventDefault()``` para o callback deve funcionar

Comment: Como pode ver testando esse código o navegador recarrega a pagina pois esse é o comportamento padrão e com o ```event.preventDefault()``` impedimos isso de acontecer

Comment: Funcionou com o event.preventDefault() ? Testei aqui e não deu certo. Estou achando que é um bug do Autocomplete do pacote formik-material-ui-lab.

Comment: Fiz o seguinte, criei um estado inicializando-o como vazio, no onChange, seto o estado com o valor de value.name. E passo esse valor para a propriedade value do Autocomplete. Dessa forma funcionou. Valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: Eu que agradeço. Bom saber disso caso eu for usar isso em algum projeto sera bem util

Answer (score 2):

Conforme o link enviado pelo Rafael Tavares no seu comentário, a documentação especifica que para você conseguir capturar o objeto selecionado você precisa utilizar o método onChange ao invés do onInputChange.
[image: Print do atributo onInputChange]

Se você trocar o onInputChange por onChange a sua variavel value vai retornar o objeto inteiro ao invés de somente o nome.
[image: Print da documentação onChange]

https://material-ui.com/pt/components/autocomplete/#controllable-states